# Find when and how often laptop crashes or force shutdown

Tags: windows-10

I am not interested in the number where we actually clicks on shutdown.
But the unintentional crash and force shutdown using the hold button of the laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78335-read-shutdown-logs-event-viewer-windows.html

Open the event viewer and filter for Event IDs 41 and 6008:

1. Click Start Button
2. Type "Event Viewer"
3. Click on the "Event Viewer" app shortcut.
4. On the left: Drill down the tree: `Event Viewer (local) > Windows Logs > System`
5. On the right: Click `Filter current log...`
6. In the textbox that says `<All Event IDs>` enter `41,6008`
7. Click OK.

You'll see an event for any time the computer shutdown unexpectedly or rebooted improperly without going through `Start > Power > Shutdown/Restart`